# How to style number_field_tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have number_filed_tag for products quantity, and it should looks like

+1-

How to make custom +,- buttons near number_field_tag?

Comment: `<input type="number">`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `<input type="number">`. Check out the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n7sxz9od/1/)

However, the buttons will not say `+1` or `-1`, they are just arrows

What you could do however, is add images of arrows and use Javascript / jQuery to change the value. I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z63k5wje/2/) to demonstrate, or view the snippet below

```js
$('.up').on('click', function() {
 var value = $(this).prev().val()
    $(this).prev().val(parseInt(value) + 1)
})

$('.down').on('click', function() {
 var value = $(this).prev().prev().val()
    $(this).prev().prev().val(parseInt(value) - 1)
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" value=10>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up up"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down down"></span>
```